# Why does the implementation functions report an error in drools 7.51.0.Final?

Tags: drools

I use accumulate with inline custom code crrectly in drools 7.33.0.Final,but get a error() in 7.51.0.Final.
The error is "Legacy accumulate can be used only with drools-mvel on classpath".so I try to implement my own accumulate functions,but has another error(xxx cannot be cast to org.kie.api.runtime.rule.AccumulateFunction).even though I totally copy the example code ,the error also happened.

```
public class TotalAccumulateFunction implements org.kie.api.runtime.rule.AccumulateFunction<TotalAccumulateFunction.TotalData>{

public void readExternal(ObjectInput in) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {

}

public void writeExternal(ObjectOutput out) throws IOException {

}

public static class TotalData implements Externalizable {
    public int total = 0;

    public TotalData() {}

    public void readExternal(ObjectInput in) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        total   = in.readInt();
    }
    public void writeExternal(ObjectOutput out) throws IOException {
        out.writeInt(total);
    }
}

public TotalData createContext() {
    return new TotalData();
}

public void init(TotalData context) {
    context.total = 0;
}

public void accumulate(TotalData context,
                       Object value) {
    context.total += ((Number) value).doubleValue();
}

public void reverse(TotalData context, Object value) {
    context.total -= ((Number) value).doubleValue();
}

public Object getResult(TotalData context) {
    return context.total == 0 ? 0 : context.total;
}

public boolean supportsReverse() {
    return true;
}

public Class< ? > getResultType() {
    return Number.class;
}
```

}

Comment: Did you try adding mvel like it said in the original error?

Comment: Add "dialect 'mvel'"? It did not wok.

Comment: No, adding the missing dependency .... You're missing an entire library/jar.

Answer (score 0):

Since Drools 7.45.0.Final `drools-mvel` has been moved to a separated module for better modularization.

See the [release notes](https://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/7.52.0.Final/drools-docs/html_single/index.html#_descope_of_mvel_and_asm_based_features).

> Drools engine usages of MVEL and ASM are isolated in a new
> drools-mvel module. This new module is strictly required on the
> classpath for all usages that do not involve the executable model.
> Note that this is not related to the dialect in use. In the usual DRL
> compilation, both Java and MVEL dialects rely on MVEL for parsing and
> on ASM for bytecode generation. In both cases, it is a must to have
> drools-mvel in your classpath.

If you plan to use the "classic" Drools with MVEL instead of the executable model, you might consider depending on the [wrapper module](https://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/7.52.0.Final/drools-docs/html_single/index.html#_new_wrapper_modules) `drools-engine-classic`

> This issue is mainly caused by the fact that users have among their
> dependencies modules like drools-core and drools-compiler that in
> reality are no more than "internal implementation details". To avoid
> similar problems in future, in the very likely case that other modules
> will be introduced to split engine in finer grained submodules and
> descope optional features, the following 2 new wrapper modules have
> been created to cover the 2 different main usage scenarios:
>
> drools-engine aggregating drools-core, drools-compiler and
> drools-model-compiler
>
> drools-engine-classic aggregating drools-core, drools-compiler and
> drools-mvel

Comment: Mind boggling how such an obviously breaking change went into a minor release instead of a major one.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas I see your point, but the release process has changed and the upstream version is moving really fast, we have a release each three weeks after all.

Comment: ... release cadence really shouldn't have anything to do with this, tbh. But the ship has sailed, as they say. :)

Comment: I did not find the corresponding example on the official website.Now the rules is in the drl files on classpath.If I want to use the "classic" drools with mveI,what should I add to the project?for example: 

rule "cumulative penalty"
dialect "mvel"
    when
        $total : Integer() from accumulate(
            init(Integer total = 0;),
            action(total++;),
            reverse(total--;),
            result(total)
        )
        eval($total > 2)
    then
    scoreHolder.addSoftConstraintMatch(kcontext, -2);
end

Comment: @normay check the two links of the doc, there is the maven module you should include. either `drools-mvel` or `drools-engine-classic`